# Как называется сортируемый список с колонками?

Tags: list, gui, java

Собственно, не могу понять, как называется вот [такой](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6Rlo.png) список с несколькими колонками?
По запросам `java list with columns`, `java grid list` гугл выдаёт не то, что нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, это больше на JTable похоже, только без сетки. Через метод setGridColor(), если не ошибаюсь, можно скрыть сетку, замаскировав её по цвету под фон